# Perforce login with no expiration ticket for scripting

Tags: perforce

For some reason I have to install a perforce server and I've been trying to automate the installation but I have a stupid issue with the fact that I can't rerun the script a day after as the session expired.

For clarification pupose:

- I'm installing perforce server on linux, the server is running a debian and I'm following the linux installation (that works) and installing the `helix-p4d` package.
- Following that I'm configuring the server using the /opt/perforce/sbin/configure-helix-p4d.sh script and passing the parameters as option to the script.
- I then follow the security recommandation of perforce for the installation: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/chapter.security.html

All the command below are executed on the perforce server.

I've done some reading and some suggest to create a ticket with no expiration using this command:

```
p4 login -a -p
```

I tried and got the tickets string to use for connection:

```
p4 -P STRING login
```

And I got asked the password... I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong there and I don't know how to check the ticket expiration date.

I tried other simpler things like:

- setting the P4PASSWD variable using `p4 set P4PASSWD=PASSWORD` , that doesn't seem to be working anymore, the value is not visible when doing a `p4 set -s`
- setting the P4PASSWD variable directly in $HOME/p4enviro file... the value appears in `p4 set -s` but `p4 login` still asks for the password.

I would really like to have the ticket thing working with no time of expiration but at this point I will take anything that prevents the password from being asked...

Does anyone knows how to set the password or tickets for it to work?

EDIT:

I also tried to change the security parameter of the perforce configuration to not require the ticket auth as in parameters 3/4 (default value) and tried the values for compatibility but I still can't set the P4PASSWD.

Comment: I suggest adding the output of `p4 counters` to this question -- is `security` set to `0` (permitting password-based auth)?  If `security` is set to `0` what exact error message do you get when running, say, `p4 -P your_password changes -m1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your user is not set to have an unlimited ticket yet.

The `p4 login -a -p` command will give you a ticket for this user that can be used on any machine, but it does *not* make that ticket unlimited. In order to change a user's ticket timeout, you need to create a group with an unlimited login timeout and then add the user to that group.

If you want to do it in the CLI, this page covers how to do that  https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2589
But you can also do it in P4Admin from any machine.

Login to P4Admin as a Super user. At the top menu, click on the Add Group button.

[image]

Then in the Group Dialog, give it a name (like Unlimited), click **Browse...** to select your user and add it to the group, then select the Unlimited radio button for **Duration before login session times out**.

[image]

After you click OK and create that group, then try once you login, the session on that machine should stay valid forever (until you manually logout or change the password).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your link was exactly what I was missing I was trying to do it with the perforce parameters where I should have gone to basics... The first example piping the password in an echo was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't have a security level that requires login tickets to be used, and you want to use direct password authentication for every command instead of ticket-based authentication, you can completely disregard `p4 login`.  The *only* purpose of `p4 login` is to give you a ticket for ticket-based authentication.  To delete any existing login ticket you might have, do:

```
p4 logout
```

Then to set the plaintext password in your environment for authentication, do:

```
p4 set P4PASSWD=your_password
```

Test that it worked by running a command that requires authentication, e.g.:

```
p4 changes -m1
```

Do not run `p4 login` if you do not want to authenticate with tickets.  `p4 login` completely disregards your `P4PASSWD` value (the idea is that if you're using tickets for security you should not be setting your password in your environment, so everything related to ticket-based authentication ignores/discourages the use of `P4PASSWD`) and will always prompt you for your password.

Note that `p4 set` and `p4 set -s` apply to different environment namespaces; if you set a variable with `p4 set`, then check it with `p4 set`:

```
p4 set P4PASSWD
```

will show you the `P4PASSWD` value for the current user.  The `-s` flag sets and queries the environment for the System user on Windows.

If the server requires ticket-based authentication (e.g. the `security` counter is set to `3`, which is the standard for admins who want a modicum of security on their Perforce installation), you will need to request the ability to create unlimited-timeout tickets.  This is done by assigning you to a `group` with `Timeout: unlimited`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that... but that doesn't work on my version, it seems that the security parameter wasn't configured correctly.... It required the p4 login command... I tried to change the value but it did not do much... Still can't set P4PASSWD...

Comment: You should edit your question to show exactly what you tried and what error message you got.  You also might need to clarify how this server was set up -- you said that you were the one installing it, which implies a default configuration.  Is this actually an existing server that's been configured to require ticket-based auth?  And why would you be running a script every day to "install" a Perforce server that runs commands against a Perforce server...?

Comment: I added the installation I'm doing and an edit at the end of the post with the test modification of the security parameter

Comment: Why are you re-running the installation script at all?  You only need to install once.

Comment: I'm running the install script only once

Comment: If you're only running the script once, what are you doing the next day that causes you to hit a ticket timeout with the script?  Is this a Groundhog Day situation?

Comment: The install script is runned only once but I'm looking to automate the isntall and have something with idempotence... The issue being that you can't really call that idempotent if some command can't work during an update because you need to log in and can't log in

Comment: I still can't figure out what exactly you're trying to do or exactly what problem you're hitting.  Based on the fragments in your question and what you just described, it *sounds* like you're essentially creating a lot of work for yourself out of nothing.  I suggest shooting a line to support@perforce.com so you can explain in more detail and they can give you guidance.